# How to add object_action that leads to a action_page.xml?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, config, admin-generator

I want to add an action that will output xml file from object's fields.

Here is an example:

```
object_actions:
  _edit: ~
  _delete: ~
  export_xliff: {label : Export Xliff, action: exportXliff}
```

This creates a button/link to `../exportXliff`, but I want the `../exportXliff.xml`.

How do I add the format from admin generator config file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can add a format here and [according to the code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfObjectRouteCollection.class.php#L95), it's seems to be only html ..

Do you need to have different format as output or only xml?

If your are using only xml, you can change the format from the action.

```
$request->setRequestFormat('xml');
```

First I was thinking of using a defined route in the routing.yml, but it seems you can't.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer! I will go a head an accept it. In fact I kind a need only xml, so your answer is good enough. Though I was hoping there is a more symfony like way of doing it(configs)

Comment: The only thing I found related to these links were the method used (get, post, etc ..) using [collection_actions](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/fr/10-Routing#chapter_10_sub_collection_actions). Otherwise, you might write your own [sfDoctrineRouteCollection](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/routing/sfDoctrineRouteCollection.class.php).